# ffmpeg RTSP stream from camera + Alsa audio mux to RTMP destination?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

Folks,

I have an IP Camera that I want to take the RTSP/H264 stream and use ffmpeg to send this to a youtube Live / RTMP service. The challenge I have is streaming the video with a separate audio feed.

I can stream just fine to Youtube if I use the stream of audio coming from the input of the IP CAM (there is an 1/8" audio mic jack on the IP Camera). But I want to hook this up to a PA system where the audio feed is actually where the PC running ffmpeg will be. Here is where I have the issue. The audio is ahead of the video by a couple of seconds.

Maybe my command line syntax is not right and that is why the the sync is way off.

If I do an ffprobe, here are my available streams:

```
$ffprobe rtsp://10.0.0.120

ffprobe version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.0.0.120':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 100 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
```

And here is the local audio card that I want to use the line input:

```
$ ffprobe -f alsa -i hw:0,0
ffprobe version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:0,0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1574855984.306477, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

Using the built-in audio input on the IPCAM (which works just fine) I'm using the following syntax:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i "rtsp://10.0.0.120" -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/thekey"
```

But trying to use the audio input on the PC, the audio is ahead of the video by at least 2 seconds.

```
$ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 6144  -i rtsp://10.0.0.120 -thread_queue_size 6144   -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:2,0 -c:a:0 aac -ar 44100 -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/thekey
```

I had to add to bump up the thread_queue_size because I was dropping frames like crazy.

I tried using the 'itsoffset' switch and that didn't seem to help much. It works fine in the positive direction, but that just delays my video even more. The negative offset didn't seem to work:

```
$ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 6144  -itsoffset -00:00:02  -i rtsp://10.0.0.120 -thread_queue_size 6144   -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:2,0 -c:a:0 aac -ar 44100 -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/thekey
```

BTW, here is what the output looks like when I stream with the above syntax:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.0.0.120:554':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.001000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 100 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, alsa, from 'hw:2,0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1574856329.559323, bitrate: 768 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 768 kb/s
[flv @ 0x10603c0] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<keyremoved>':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 100 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

Any ideas on how to tweak this so I can delay the audio? The sound and video quality looks great...its just sync.

Thanks!

-J

Comment: I see you are forcing -f flv. I always thought flv produced poorly with audio/video duration why no try another format.

Comment: If I don't force it, then I get the following error message and ffmpeg exits: ```[NULL @ 0x23dc220] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/```

Comment: What do you suggest for a format to try for Youtube live?

Comment: How about the normal .mpg or .mp4 it may help, I would try a couple, it may make a difference in timing. Good luck with that.